# nginx append slash to domain name only

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I need to append `/` to `https://my_domain.com`. However for the rest of urls all appended slashes must be removed. For example:

```
https://my_domain.com
```

must be changed to

```
https://my_domain.com/
```

And:

```
https://my_domain.com/some_page/
```

must be rewritten to

```
https://my_domain.com/some_page
```

This is part of my nginx config:

```
location / {
    # This is what I have tried so far 
    rewrite ^(.*)my_domain.com$ $1/ break; 

    # Remove trailing double slashes.
    if ($request_uri ~ "^[^?]*?//") {
        rewrite "^" $scheme://$host$uri permanent;
    }

    # Remove trailing slashes.      
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

    # Rewrite page/0 and page/1 from url.
    # rewrite ^/(.*)/page/[01]$ /$1 redirect;

    proxy_pass                      http://backend_web;   
    proxy_set_header                Host $host;
    proxy_set_header                X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

I can remove all slashes from urls. But I cannot append one slash to the main page, i.e. https://my_domain.com.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you actually need this? Most browsers don't show the trailing slash for the domain only or remove them themselves in the address field. There is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Does it affect SEO? SEO company asks us to this for better indexing by search bots?

Comment: I think you need a better SEO company. The key to SEO these days is to create great content that's easy to access on any device, a fast website, and have plenty of good quality links to it from reputable websites.